# O meu site cria duas scroll bars quando a resolução no eixo X é diminuída

Tags: html5, css3

O meu site cria duas scroll bars a principal e outra na div que contem a imagem dos cartazes dos fimes quando a resolução no eixo X é diminuída. Alguém pode-me ajudar a resolver isto?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Manjari&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body, #root, .render{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background: #111;
    font-family: 'Manjari', sans-serif;
}
.mainBanner{
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/7XY9yyb/fundo.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.variacao{
    height: 10%;
    margin-top: 186px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #111 100%);
}
.wall{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.topContainer{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.topContainer h1{
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e50914;
}
.wellcomemsg{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 280px;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    color: #FFF;
}
.btns button{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e50914;
    background: #e50914;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.multi{
    position: relative;
}
.multi p{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 40px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-top: 12%;
}
.multi img{
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    opacity: 0.95;
    margin-left: 60px;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.multi img:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
hr{
    border-color: #ccc; 
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .variacao{
        overflow-x: hidden;
        margin-top: 70.8px;
    }
    .wellcomemsg{
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-top: 23.5px;
    }
    .btns button{
        margin-top: 40px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .multi img{
        margin-top: 30px;
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 5%;
    }
    .multi p{
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 8%;
        margin-right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="render">
<div class="mainBanner">
    <div class="wall">
        <div class="topContainer">
            <h1>IMM | YouWatch</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="wellcomemsg">
            <p>Bem-vindo a YouWatch</p>
            <p>Cria uma conta gratis ou experimenta</p>
            <p>Uma conta paga durante 1 Mês</p>
            <div class="btns">
                <button>Criar uma conta</button>
                <button>Iniciar Sessão</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="variacao"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="multi">
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/q9s3R9v/multi.png" alt="Multi Plataformas" title="Multi Plataformas"/>
<p>Veja os seus filmes e series favoritos onde e quando quiser!</p>
</div>
<hr />
<p>T</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Não é uma solução perfeita. Vc vai ver que em determinados momentos o scroll ainda aparece. Mas aqui tem uma solução simples que deve funcionar em 90% das telas.*** *O ajuste fino só usando `@media` para ficar 100% em todas as telas mesmo...*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seu problema é que vc colocou um elemento filho com `margin top` dentro de um pai que tem 100% de altura, isso faz o conteúdo de dentro do pai "crescer" para mais de 100% que é a altura dele, ai cria a barra de rolagem no *container*.

Para corrigir isso faça o alinhamento do filho que tem a sombra na imagem com `position:absolut` e `bottom:0`. foi a melhor maneira que encontrei. E para controlar o tamanho da fonte usa a media em `VW` não em `PX`, essa é a maneira mais prática, mas vc tb pode usar media queries para controlar isso de forma mais profissional https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Manjari&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
#root,
.render {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #111;
    font-family: 'Manjari', sans-serif;
}

.mainBanner {
    background: url('https://i.ibb.co/7XY9yyb/fundo.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.variacao {
    height: 10%;
    /* margin-top: 186px; */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #111 100%);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}


.wall {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.topContainer {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.topContainer h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e50914;
}

.wellcomemsg {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 280px;
    font-size: 5vw;
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    color: #FFF;
}

.btns button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e50914;
    background: #e50914;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.multi {
    position: relative;
}

.multi p {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 40px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-top: 12%;
}

.multi img {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    opacity: 0.95;
    margin-left: 60px;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.multi img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

hr {
    border-color: #ccc;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .variacao {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        margin-top: 70.8px;
    }

    .wellcomemsg {
        font-size: 30px;
        margin-top: 23.5px;
    }

    .btns button {
        margin-top: 40px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .multi img {
        margin-top: 30px;
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 5%;
    }

    .multi p {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 8%;
        margin-right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="render">
    <div class="mainBanner">
        <div class="wall">
            <div class="topContainer">
                <h1>IMM | YouWatch</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wellcomemsg">
                <p>Bem-vindo a YouWatch</p>
                <p>Cria uma conta gratis ou experimenta</p>
                <p>Uma conta paga durante 1 Mês</p>
                <div class="btns">
                    <button>Criar uma conta</button>
                    <button>Iniciar Sessão</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="variacao"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="multi">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/q9s3R9v/multi.png" alt="Multi Plataformas" title="Multi Plataformas" />
        <p>Veja os seus filmes e series favoritos onde e quando quiser!</p>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <p>T</p>
</div>
```